# SQL nested select in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data in a table called 'testing' in SQL Server:

```
ID  Name    Department
1   Person1 IT
2   Person2 Finance
3   Person3 IT
4   Person4 IT
5   Person5 Finance
```

The SQL Query I am using is:

```
SELECT Department AS '@Department',
(
    SELECT Name
    FROM testing
    WHERE Department = Department
    FOR XML PATH ('Person'), TYPE
)
FROM testing
GROUP BY Department
FOR XML PATH ('Department'), TYPE
```

Now the problem is that the output is not being grouped by department. Instead, all the persons are included in Finance and again in IT.

Where I am wrong?

Thanks in advance

---

The current output is:

```
<Department Department="Finance">
  <Person>
    <Name>Person1</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person2</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person3</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person4</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person5</Name>
  </Person>
</Department>
<Department Department="IT">
  <Person>
    <Name>Person1</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person2</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person3</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person4</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person5</Name>
  </Person>
</Department>
```

But my desired output is:

```
<Department Department="Finance">
  <Person>
    <Name>Person2</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person5</Name>
  </Person>
</Department>
<Department Department="IT">
  <Person>
    <Name>Person1</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person3</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Person4</Name>
  </Person>
</Department>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use aliases because you have two references to the `testing` table:

```
SELECT Department AS '@Department',
(
    SELECT Name
    FROM testing t2
    WHERE t2.Department = t.Department
    FOR XML PATH ('Person'), TYPE
)
FROM testing t
GROUP BY Department
FOR XML PATH ('Department'), TYPE
```

Your query had `Department = Department`.  These both refer to the inner `testing`, so they just choose the non-NULL values of Department.